# Bott Periodicity: Morse and K-Theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, morse-theory

Is there an easy way to see the equivalence of the two statements of Bott periodicity via K-Theory and the original Morse Theory proof?

So, $$BU \times \mathbb{Z} \simeq \Omega^2BU$$ and 
$$K(X)\otimes K(S^2) \cong K(X\times S^2)$$

I know there is the Bott paper that explicitly comments on this, but it is written in French. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should help at least a little: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fundamental+product+theorem+in+topological+K-theory

Comment: Considering the reference to Bott's paper, it's probable the OP was asking a more subtle question: why does the Bott map (something defined in terms of grassmanians and paths) agree with multiplication by the Bott class? In other words, there's a little diagram of isomorphisms and it's not at all obvious it commutes... I think Bott's paper checks this.